# Many to Many / Circular reference issue Jackson+Spring+Hibernate

Tags: json, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc, jackson

**Course.java**

```
@Entity
@Table
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Course {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @NotEmpty
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "subject_course", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "subject_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Subject> subjects = new HashSet<Subject>();

    ---- getter/setter ----
```

**Subject.java**

```
@Entity
@Table
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Subject {

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "subjects", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.DELETE, CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    private Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<Course>();

    ---- getter/setter ----
```

Request configuration in Spring:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/courses", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> getAllCourses() {
    List<Course> courses = courseService.getAllCourses();
    if (courses.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Message>(new Message("error", "No course found!"), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Course>>(courses, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**Hibernate Version: 4.2.0.Final 

Spring Version: 3.2.8.RELEASE 

Jackson:**

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.4</version>
 </dependency>
```

**Expecting O/P**

```
 [{
      "id": 1,
      "description": "BCA",
      "subjects":[{
           "id":1,
           "description":"Physics",
           "courses":[1,2,3] //Either show blank array or only ids
      }]
 },{
      "id": 2,
      "description": "BSC",
      "subjects":[{
           "id":1,
           "description":"Physics",
           "courses":[1,2,3]
      }]
 },{
      "id": 3,
      "description": "BA",
      "subjects":[{
           "id":1,
           "description":"Physics",
           "courses":[1,2,3]
      }]
 },]
```

But getting O/P:

```
 [
   {
     "id": 1,
     "description": "BCA",
     "subjects": [
       {
         "id": 1,
         "description": "Math",
         "staffs": [],
         "courses": [
           {
             "id": 4,
             "description": "BDA",
             "subjects": [
               1
             ],
             "students": []
           },
           {
             "id": 3,
             "description": "BBA",
             "subjects": [
               1
             ],
             "students": []
           },
           1
         ],
         "students": []
       }
     ],
     "students": [
       {
         "id": 1,
         "name": "",
         "age": 0,
         "gender": null,
         "course": 1,
         "subjects": []
       }
     ]
   },
   3,
   4
 ]
```

As per actual o/p, it is stopping the recursion at second level. But my requirement is not to repeat the same objects data from child... It means Course must not repeat its data in Subject's course property. Similarly, if call the same from Subject then subject should not repeat Course subject property value. It is better to skip, if can't then just display id values separated by comma.

Please advise how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@JsonIgnore` in the Subject class like this:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "subjects", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@Cascade({CascadeType.DELETE, CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<Course>();
```

Comment: It's not giving consistent result:
[
  {
"id": 1,
 "description": "BCA",
"subjects": [
{
   "id": 1,
        "description": "Math",
        "staffs": [],
        "students": []
      }
    ],
    "students": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "",
        "age": 0,
        "gender": null,
        "course": 1,
        "subjects": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "description": "BBA",
    "subjects": [
      1
    ],
    "students": []
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "description": "BDA",
    "subjects": [
      1
    ],
    "students": []
  }
]

Comment: What's not consistent here?

Comment: The o/p in comment I posted, you can see in first object(id="1") subjects property represent an array of objects however in second object(id="3") it shows only id of subjects. It seems jackson converter uses only show id(because of the `@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")` code) for repeated objects...

Comment: Also, it seems when I will fetch subjects object then it will completely remove Course object... I don't want that to happen....